# How to mock input to a function with multiple iterations (for example, while True with an exit condition) using pytest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have a main() function in which input is called several times, after which an answer is given or nothing. I need to test cases where the user first enters one line, and then exits the loop by writing the line "Exit". It's not very clear how you can mock this using monkeypatch

```
def main():
    fsm_number = create_fsm_number()
    fsm_abb = create_fsm_abb()
    print("If you want exit, enter 'Exit'")
    while True:
        input_string = input("Enter your string: ")
        if input_string == "Exit":
            break
        check_if_number(fsm_number, input_string)
        check_if_abb(fsm_abb, input_string)
```

At the same time, several monkeypatch.setattr does not work, because only the last one is counted

```
def test_main_scenario(input_user, expected, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("builtins.input", lambda _: input_user)
    monkeypatch.setattr("builtins.input", lambda _: "Exit")
    main()
    fake_output = StringIO()
    monkeypatch.setattr("sys.stdout", fake_output)
    output = fake_output.getvalue()

    assert output == expected
```